# for loop incrementing is decreasing the given value instead of incrementing it

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop

hey im new to JS and i have been playing around with it. today i got stuck at this problem pls help me understand what im doing wrong.

i know the code looks chaotic but what i want to do here is that i want to remove items from idList that are not found in onlinelike. but i found that something was wrong and the for loop which was meant to increment i like 0,1,2 etc was instead counting down.

please help.

```js
const idList = ['group1 1', 'group2 2', 'group3 3', 'group1 4'];

const onlinelike = ['group1 1', 'group3 2', 'group2 3', 'group1 4'];

var RemovedList = [];

if (idList != null) {
  idList.forEach(item => {
    if (onlinelike != null) {
      for (i = 0; i < onlinelike.length; i++) {
        if (onlinelike[i].split(' ')[0] === item.split(' ')[0]) {
          if (onlinelike[i].split(' ')[1] !== item.split(' ')[1]) {
            console.log(item, 'to to be removed')
            console.log(i);
          }
        }
      }
    }
  });
}
```

also when removed an if statement from it it started acting even more weirdly counting like 0,3,2,1,0,3

```js
const idList = ['group1 1', 'group2 2', 'group3 3', 'group1 4'];

const onlinelike = ['group1 1', 'group3 2', 'group2 3', 'group1 4'];

var RemovedList = [];

if (idList != null) {
  idList.forEach(item => {
    if (onlinelike != null) {
      for (i = 0; i < onlinelike.length; i++) {
        if (onlinelike[i].split(' ')[0] === item.split(' ')[0]) {
          console.log(item, 'to to be removed')
          console.log(i);
        }
      }
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: You will log the `i` variable only when it matches your `if` condition. In your first example, on the first iteration, the condition is true when `i===3` and on the next item, the condition is true when `i===2`

Comment: @Weedoze ah sorry i didnt even think about that should i remove the question or something?

Comment: I think that you can delete this question as it doesn't solve anything and it won't help anyone else

Comment: @Weedoze sry i tried but stackoverflow wont let me since people answered im very sorry for wasting your time

Answer (score 0):

In order to remove items from `idList` that are not present in `onlinelike`, you can use logic like below:

```js
const idList = ['group1 1', 'group2 2', 'group3 3', 'group1 4'];

const onlinelike = ['group1 1', 'group3 2', 'group2 3', 'group1 4'];

idList.forEach((item) => {
  if(!onlinelike.includes(item)) {
    console.log(`Item to be removed ${item}`);
  }
})
```

This code can be simplified even further if you are willing to use utility libraries like [lodash](https://lodash.com/). We can easily remove items from array as below:

```js
const idList = ['group1 1', 'group2 2', 'group3 3', 'group1 4'];
const onlinelike = ['group1 1', 'group3 2', 'group2 3', 'group1 4'];

_.remove(idList, (item) => !onlinelike.includes(item));

console.log(idList);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.20/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

[_.remove](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#remove) here is function provided by lodash.

Answer (score 0):

using `.filter` and `.includes()`

```js
const idList = ['group1 1', 'group2 2', 'group3 3', 'group1 4'];
const onlinelike = ['group1 1', 'group3 2', 'group2 3', 'group1 4'];

var RemovedList = idList.filter(item=> !onlinelike.includes(item))

console.log(RemovedList)
```